PSpice invalid expression after simulation
Using PSpice for TI I get this error when I try to measure COS, RMS etc. of any signal
detected by the probes in the schematic:


I looked everywhere, couldn't find anything similar.
It seems impossible to me that PSpice does not allow you to calculate the RMS value!
Maybe it's a syntax problem, but I don't understand which
EDIT:


So MAX() works fine but RMS() doesn't?

@SteKulov exactly

Someone else seems to have had the same exact problem.  Do PWR(,) and AVG() work?  If they do, you might be able to do something like PWR(AVG(PWR(V(V_LI),2)),0.5)

I've just tried AVG(V(V_HI)) where "V_H" his a PWM square wave and I have the same problem @SteKulov

I read the guide (the openable help directly on Spice) and found the table in the picture just added to the main post. It seems to indicate that AVG and RMS are not supported by Spice @SteKulov

I saw that too but I believe what "NO" means is that the function can't be used in SPICE expressions, but a TRACE expression should be fine.  If "NO" means what you think it means then MAX() shouldn't work either, but it does...which is why I asked that in the first comment.

you are right. Unfortunately, I can't ask directly on TI's e2e forum because for a while now only certain "emails" can post new questions. The interesting thing is that I can plot the RMS value of the signal I am interested in. But since I need it in the efficiency calculation, I don't know what I could do with that curve ... I need a value to enter into the calculator

I think I may have found something.  Try YatLastX(RMS(V(V_LI))).

Great! It works! I don't know how I would have done it without your help. However, I hope that this is a "reliable" calculation, because I am simulating a half bridge gate driver with two mosfets (Silicon) HS and LS and both with switching frequency = 10kHz and with 80kHz the calculated RMS power is the same ... it seems a bit strange to me.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
